# What happens with NotificationListenerService and Android versions below 18

Tags: android

I have an app that extends NotificationListenerService which is API 18+. It compiles with minSdkVersion 16 in AndroidStudio which is fine. It's not critical if this is ignored as I'm only using it to clear a notification, but in 17- versions will it crash or just ignore? I don't have a phone with a lower version to test and can't use the emulator because it involves bluetooth.

UPDATE: Using

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
```

above the method and

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
    ... Various code fragments.
}
```

worked fine with the Jelly Bean device I tested it on.

Answer (score 0):

The system will not call your `NotificationListenerService` (obviously: it doesn't know what it is). However, if you manually start the service yourself, then your app **will** crash as the superclass will not be found.